# What is this piece of equipment Luke had on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, object-identification

When Luke breaks out camp his first night on Dagobah, he sets out some cases and then puts a glowing device on top of one. It looks like some sort of small heater, but someone on a forum said it was a power unit. I did a few quick searches but couldn't find anything about the prop. I did find a good screenshot, though. I've circled the device I'm asking about.

**What is this small heater-looking unit supposed to be?**

[image]

Comment: It's a small recharger unit

Comment: The heater-looking object turned out to be a... heater?

Comment: Hah.  You and Valorum in cahoots?  ;-)  No offense, but I always thought this one was incredibly obvious.

Comment: @can-ned_food - It's a lighty-uppy-droid-charger-thingy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a [Fusion Furnace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_furnace). In addition to creating heat and light, it can also be used to charge a droid.

> *“You ready for some power?” Luke asked Artoo, who was patiently waiting for his own form of nourishment. Luke took a small fusion furnace from an equipment box and ignited it, welcoming even the tiny glow thrown off by the small heating device, then took a power cable and attached it to Artoo through a protuberance that roughly resembled a nose. As power radiated through Artoo’s electronic innards, the stout robot whistled his appreciation.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> *Luke had retrieved a box of emergency provisions from his X-wing and
> set up his camp in a clearing. As he ignited **a compact fusion furnace**
> that he’d placed on a rotten log beside R2-D2, the droid beeped at
> him.*
>
> *“What?” Luke said. “Ready for some power? Okay. Let’s see now.” He ran
> a power cable from the furnace to the droid. “Put that in there,” he
> said to himself as he plugged the cable into R2-D2’s socket. “There
> you go.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

[image]